# Search drives for a text file with exact word inside and make a change

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I try to find a file inside a disk and then make a change. I can do it with a file dialog but the problem is that the disk is not shown at computer folders (it should be like that). So I try to find in which disk that file is and then hold the filename so I can make changes (is a text file).

As it looks the code find the file but I can't keep the filename after that and maybe something have to do with after some try's I see that say's the file is in use (i am not sure when it does that).

Thanks for any help in advance Panos

```
Public Class Form1

Dim FileFOund As String

 Private Sub FindFile()

    Dim drives As String() = Directory.GetLogicalDrives()
    Dim tempfile As String = "temp.txt"

    For Each drive As String In drives
        Dim driveFound As String = drive
    If File.Exists(driveFound & tempfile) Then
         Dim lines() As String = File.ReadLines(driveFound & tempfile)
                If lines(1) = "#temp" Then
                    LblFileExists.Text = "Temp found"
                    FileFOund = driveFound & tempfile
                Else
                    LblFileExists.Text = "Temp not found"
                End If
            Else
                LblFileExists.Text = "Temp found"
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

and then i need to change a line inside the fileFound

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If System.IO.File.Exists(fileFound) Then
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileFound)
        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
            If lines(i).Contains("Anything") Then
                lines(i) = "to change" 
            End If
        Next
        File.WriteAllLines(fileFound, lines)
        MessageBox.Show("Changes complete!", "Temp")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Something Wrong!", "Temp")
    End If

End Sub
```

I hope is clear for you, thanks again.

Comment: Do you intend to look *only* in the root of the drives, e.g. for "C:\test.txt", "D:\test.txt",...?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes Andrew, no need for sub folders. The file will be there for sure just the Drives letter can't be sure which one.

Comment: You should make the `FindFile` method into a function to call from the button click handler.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks a lot Andrew, i post the answer as it works right now. You was right, i din't make a function but needed to be two different things to work (at least as i understand it :) ). For now looks it work great, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Public Class Form1

Dim FileFOund As String

Private Sub FindFile()

    Dim drives As String() = Directory.GetLogicalDrives()

    For Each drive As String In drives
        Dim driveFound As String = drive
    If File.Exists(driveFound & tempfile) Then
         FileFOund = driveFound & tempfile
        End If
    Next
      If File.Exists(driveFound & "temp.txt") Then
Dim lines() As String = Filter(File.ReadAllLines(driveFound & "temp.txt"), "#Temp")
               If UBound(lines) = 0 Then
                    LblFileExists.Text = "Temp found"                        
                Else
                    LblFileExists.Text = "Temp not found"
                End If
            Else
                LblFileExists.Text = "Temp found"
            End If

End Sub

     Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If System.IO.File.Exists(fileFound) Then
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileFound & "temp.txt")
        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
            If lines(i).Contains("Anything") Then
                lines(i) = "to change" 
            End If
        Next
        File.WriteAllLines(fileFound & "temp.txt", lines)
        MessageBox.Show("Changes complete!", "Temp")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Something Wrong!", "Temp")
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```